# Trying to plot a geographic shape file of the UK in python

Tags: python, shapefile, geo

I have tried to install Geopython on 3.7 the Fiona/GDAL failed miserably in the install. Next, I have just tried to query the file with the shape reader and directly plot the points.

While I have had some success with an example on gis.StackOverflow (credit to user681), I used the shapefile from the UK gov website. When I plot the boundaries I get horrible point correlation.

[image]

My code is here.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import shapefile   

ukmap = shapefile.Reader("./Archive/UK_map.shp")

txt_shapes = []
for ukmapshape in ukmap.shapes(): 
    listx=[]
    listy=[]   
    for x,y in ukmapshape.points:
        listx.append(x)
        listy.append(y)
    txt_shapes.append([listx,listy])

for zone in txt_shapes:
    x,y = zone
    plt.plot(x,y)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

The question is, it this likely the point order, a.k.a. my file or is my method wrong?

http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/nuts-level-1-january-2018-ultra-generalised-clipped-boundaries-in-the-united-kingdom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to consider the parts of a shape, which contains the end indices of each part/start index of the following part.
Here is what worked for me:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import shapefile   

ukmap = shapefile.Reader("./Archive/UK_map.shp")

txt_shapes = []
for ukmapshape in ukmap.shapeRecords(): 
    listx=[]
    listy=[]
    # parts contains end index of each shape part
    parts_endidx = ukmapshape.shape.parts.tolist()
    parts_endidx.append(len(ukmapshape.shape.points) - 1)
    for i in range(len(ukmapshape.shape.points)):
        x, y = ukmapshape.shape.points[i]
        if i in parts_endidx:
            # we reached end of part/start new part
            txt_shapes.append([listx,listy])
            listx = [x]
            listy = [y]
        else:
            # not end of part
            listx.append(x)
            listy.append(y)

for zone in txt_shapes:
    x,y = zone
    plt.plot(x,y)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to run your code. If I use *shapefile.shapeRecords* instead of *shapefile.shapes*. I get this error........... 

\site-packages\shapefile.py", line 884, in __dbfHeader
    raise ShapefileException("Shapefile Reader requires a shapefile or file-like object. (no dbf file found)")
___________________________________________________
ShapefileException: Shapefile Reader requires a shapefile or file-like object. (no dbf file found)

Comment: @Cromex you need the dbf file next to the shp file, the dbf file is also in the zip from the website you provided.